# Apache2 shows different Django version?

Tags: python, django, apache2, mod-wsgi

I installed Django 2.1.7 and mod-wsgi for Python3 (Ubuntu 18.04 LTS). Afterwards I added following configuration parameters to the apache2.conf file of the apache2 server:

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/mysite/mysite/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonPath /var/www/html/mysite
WSGIPythonHome /usr/

<Directory /var/www/html/mysite/>
<Files wsgi.py>
    Require all granted
</Files>
</Directory>
```

The mysite Django project is just a default sample project. When I am accessing www..com/test it returns following error message:

```
ImportError at /admin
cannot import name 'path'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://<sitename>.com/test
Django Version: 1.11.11
Exception Type: ImportError
Exception Value:    
cannot import name 'path'
Exception Location: /var/www/html/mysite/mysite/urls.py in <module>, line 17
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python3
Python Version: 3.6.7
Python Path:    
['/var/www/html/mysite',
 '/usr/lib/python36.zip',
 '/usr/lib/python3.6',
 '/usr/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']
```

But if I execute "

> python3 -m django --version

" it shows me the correct installed version (2.1.7). I also checked if maybe another (old) Django version is installed on the server but could not find anything. So why does Apache or Django says version 1.11.11 and what would the solution look like?

Comment: `WSGIPythonHome /usr/` looks incorrect. Did you install `libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3`? Are you using a virtual environment.

Comment: @Alasdair `libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3` is installed. The parameter should be correct, because when I am changing it the site with the error print is not loading anymore. And I am not using a virtual environment. It should also work without it.

Comment: Are you using a virtual environment? What do you get when you run `/usr/bin/python3 -m django --version`.

Comment: 2.1.7 and no I am not using a virtual environment.